# Displacement word problem

Tags: physics

In the figure below, a radar station detects an airplane approaching directly from the east. At first observation, the range to the plane is $d_1 = 380\ \text m$ at $40^\circ$ above the horizon. The airplane is tracked for another $123^\circ$ in the vertical east–west plane, the range at final contact being $d_2 = 800\ \text m$. Find the displacement of the airplane during the period of observation.

[[image: 1]]

I'm not sure what to do. I think I need to find the $i,j$ vectors. So, do I convert $d_1$ into $i$ by manipulating $380$ and $40$ somehow? And then the same for $d_2,j$, $800$ and $123$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In the vertical east-west plane, the radar and the two positions of the airplane form a triangle in which you know two sides and an angle. To find the third side use the Law of Cosines.

Comment: Should I do 380 times cos40 for the d1 to get i?